# How to check whether a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable or not

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

It is not clear for me how to check whether a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable or not. For example, $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{(0, 0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x, y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$$
Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ of $f(x, y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ exist and are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{(0, 0)\}.$ Thus $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{(0, 0)\}.$

Comment: To show that the partial derivatives exists I've tried to show that there exists the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h, y) - f(x, y)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \Big(\frac{x + h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2 + y^2}} - \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\Big).$$  Hence we obtain $\infty \cdot 0$. How do we solve this? Thank you!

Comment: In fact: you don't have to.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: Then how do we prove that the partial derivatives exist?

Comment: They are composed by continuous functions.